# compile phalcon php openshift

Tags: openshift, phalcon

Im trying to compile phalcon php on openshift using this 
http://www.sitepoint.com/nginx-php5-5-phalcon-openshift/

Everything is ok, but I cant finish compilation of module:
There is no error just ssh session is closing.

> cd app-root/runtime/repo/cphalcon/build ./install
>
> creating libtool
>
> appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
>
> configure: creating ./config.status
>
> config.status: creating config.h
>
> /bin/sh
>   /var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/app-root/runtime/repo/cphalcon/build/64bits/libtool
>   --mode=compile gcc  -I. -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/app-root/runtime/repo/cphalcon/build/64bits
>   -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/app-root/runtime/repo/cphalcon/build/64bits/include
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/app-root/runtime/repo/cphalcon/build/64bits/main
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/app-root/runtime/repo/cphalcon/build/64bits
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/diy//runtime//php5/include/php
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/diy//runtime//php5/include/php/main
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/diy//runtime//php5/include/php/TSRM
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/diy//runtime//php5/include/php/Zend
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/diy//runtime//php5/include/php/ext
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/diy//runtime//php5/include/php/ext/date/lib
>   -DPHALCON_RELEASE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -march=native -mtune=native -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fvisibility=hidden   -c /var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/app-root/runtime/repo/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.zep.c
>   -o phalcon.lo  mkdir .libs
>
> gcc -I.
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/app-root/runtime/repo/cphalcon/build/64bits
>   -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/app-root/runtime/repo/cphalcon/build/64bits/include
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/app-root/runtime/repo/cphalcon/build/64bits/main
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/app-root/runtime/repo/cphalcon/build/64bits
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/diy//runtime//php5/include/php
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/diy//runtime//php5/include/php/main
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/diy//runtime//php5/include/php/TSRM
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/diy//runtime//php5/include/php/Zend
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/diy//runtime//php5/include/php/ext
>   -I/var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/diy//runtime//php5/include/php/ext/date/lib
>   -DPHALCON_RELEASE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -march=native -mtune=native -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fvisibility=hidden -c /var/lib/openshift/559fb612500446f5360001bb/app-root/runtime/repo/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.zep.c
>   -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/phalcon.o
>
> Connection to phalcon-blendsoftmain.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
>
> Connection to phalcon-blendsoftmain.rhcloud.com closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your ssh session is probably timing out before your build completes.  You can either run your build in the background (using &), or you can change the OpenShift SSH Timeout.

```
rhc ssh <application>
unset TMOUT
```

Refer to this post for more information:
https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-set-the-ssh-timer-longer

Comment: I was trying run it in background with &,  with screen but screen is unavailable, when I unset TMOUT behavior is exactly the same. I looks like build process is blocking all my account, When I run build process in background then logout, wait a minute then I cant login with ssh again until background process working:

darek@blendsoft:~$ ssh  559fb612500446f5360001bb@phalcon-blendsoftmain.rhcloud.com
Last login: Thu Jul 16 05:17:33 2015 from 
Connection to phalcon-blendsoftmain.rhcloud.com closed.
darek@blendsoft:~$